# How can I search the CMU pronunciation dictionary to see if a certain arpabet pronunciation exists?

Tags: python

Given a list of arpabet tokens which encode a random utterance, I want to be able to see if the arpabet string is actually in the CMU pronunciation dict. If it is, I also want the word it matched with in the dictionary.

Is there any way I could do this in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you want to do this using CMU Sphinx in Python or by yourself, but I've come up with a reasonable solution anyways. Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
with open('dic.dict') as f:
    cmu_dict = {}
    for entry in f:
        tokens = []
        for t in entry.split():
            tokens.append(t)
        cmu_dict[tokens[0]] = tokens[1:] # index dict by word, value are phonemes

my_arpabets_list = [
    ['P', 'AH', 'L', 'IY', 'S', 'M', 'IH', 'N'],
    ['D', 'IH', 'L', 'AH', 'T', 'EY', 'SH', 'AH', 'N'],
]

for arpabet_tokens in my_arpabets_list:
    found = False
    for word, pronunciation in cmu_dict.items():
        if pronunciation == arpabet_tokens:
            print('match: %s %s' % (word, ' '.join(pronunciation)))
            found = True
            break
    if not found:
        print('error: could not find a word for tokens %s' % arpabet_tokens)
```

By executing the code I could get the following output:

```
$ ./read.py 
match: policemen P AH L IY S M IH N
error: could not find a word for tokens ['D', 'IH', 'L', 'AH', 'T', 'EY', 'SH', 'AH', 'N']
```

Assuming you have Pocketsphinx installed, you can replace the file `dic.dict` by the default dictionary for the English language that is installed alongside the package at `/usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict` to test it.

Comment: Thank you so much! This seems to be working, although it is taking a long time. If I wanted to do a little preprocessing and invert the dictionary/create a separate inverted dictionary where the arpabet pronunciations are the keys and the words are the values so that it is easy to simply do a quick check like 'arpabet_tokens in dict' and get the dict.get(arpabet_tokens) => word, how would I do that?

Comment: @Zvintāvé you might have problems indexing a dictionary by arpabets due to homographs (or heterographs?), which are different words that share the same pronunciation, such as "to", "two" and "too".